# Phaser 3 Collider clipping

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, clipping, collider

So i am kinda new to Phaser and i find it prety hard to find any good information on this topic. My Problem is that i can push my colliders in to each other (see gif).

https://imgur.com/KI1RJQA.gif "What i mean"

So right now i have a system where i keep track of the last valid position of the player and if they collide i set them back to it. But i was thinking that there has to be a better way of doing it so thats why i came here.

```
let TopWall = this.add.tileSprite(400, 100, 1800, 100, 'wall');
this.physics.add.existing(TopWall);

this.walls = this.add.group();
this.walls.addMultiple([TopWall]);

this.walls.children.iterate(function(wall) {
            wall.body.immovable = true;
        })

this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 300, 'idel', 0);

this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.walls,(player, wall) =>  {
            // this.player.x = this.player.lastPos.x;
            // this.player.y = this.player.lastPos.y;
})
```

i use the arcade physics btw.

Comment: Welocom the funny HTML5 #gamedev community :D So you want the sprite to collide with the walls ? or you want that when it collides with the walls it returns to a certain place ? I see in the gif that the sprite that is pushed into the walls can throught into them but when you move the sprite it collides with them

Comment: @nazimboudeffa Thank's for your welcoming answer. I want the player to collid normaly with the wall, so i want to stop them from being pushed inside the wall.
They should not be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade'
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

var topWall;
var player;
var alien1;

function preload ()
{
  this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png');
  this.load.image('alien1', 'sprites/phaser-alien.png');
  this.load.image('wall', 'sprites/block.png');
}

function create ()
{ 
  topWall = this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 2000, 95, 'wall');
  this.physics.add.existing(topWall);
  topWall.body.immovable = true;
  
  player = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 100, 'dude');
  alien1 = this.physics.add.sprite(400, 100, 'alien1');
  
  cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
 
  player.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
  this.physics.add.collider(player, topWall);
  this.physics.add.collider(player, alien1);
  
}

function update ()
{ 
  if (cursors.left.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityX(-160);
  }
  else if (cursors.right.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityX(160);
  }
  else if (cursors.down.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(160);

  } 
  else if (cursors.up.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(-160);
  }
}

function myCollisionHandler ()
{
 //console.log("collision") 
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.18.1/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```